# C# (Xamarin) WaitHandle.WaitAny returning Int32.MaxValue (0x7FFF FFFF)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, handle, waithandle

The documentation for WaitHandle.WaitAny Method (WaitHandle[], Int32) says it returns "The array index of the object that satisfied the wait, or WaitTimeout if no object satisfied the wait and a time interval equivalent to millisecondsTimeout has passed" and in the Assembly Browser I see that WaitHandle.WaitTimeout is 258.

So why do I sometimes get 0x7fffffff (Int32.MaxValue) as a return value from this function?

Is this a known bug in WaitAny(), or just a line missing from the documentation?

ADDED LATER:

By the way, the error happens a couple of times, then goes away, without me doing anything to "fix" the handles or anything like that.

[Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189983%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[Xamarin Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAny/p/System.Threading.WaitHandle[]/System.Int32/)

Code:

```
class CommandQueue
{
    EventWaitHandle m_abortRequest = new EventWaitHandle (false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
    Semaphore m_commandCount = new Semaphore (0, 10000);

    public CommandQueue ()
    {
        m_processTask = new Task(() => Process ());
        m_processTask.Start ();
    }

    public async Task Process()
    {
        WaitHandle [] handles = new WaitHandle [2];
        handles [0] = m_abortRequest;
        handles [1] = m_commandCount;

        for (;;)
        {
            int wait = WaitHandle.WaitAny (handles, 500);
            if (wait == WaitHandle.WaitTimeout)
            {
                OnIdleTimer ();
            }
            else if (wait == 0)
            {
                // SNIP: Code to handle a request to abort the processing of commands  
                break;
            }
            else if (wait == 1)
            {
                // SNIP: Code to process the next command in the queue
                await Process(nextCommand);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine ("*** Unexpected WaitAny(" + wait + " = 0x" + wait.ToString("X6") + ")!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you included a link to the documentation in your question.

Comment: You can see here https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/waithandle.cs and also in code of .NET framework itself, that there is constant named `int WAIT_FAILED = 0x7FFFFFFF;`, and it can be returned from `WaitAny`. Unfortunately I cannot tell under what conditions exactly it is returned, but this at least indicates this is not a bug but expected behavior.

Comment: Are you catching exceptions thrown by the call or just examining the return value?

Comment: Very hard to believe something this basic could be broken.  0x102 is a very Windows-specific value, matches the value of WAIT_TIMEOUT returned by WaitForMultipleObjects().  it won't necessarily port well to the Unixes, their waits are implemented very differently.  So make sure it is not just a logging problem.

Comment: I'm not catching exceptions, you're right I should be doing that!  But I'm not seeing any exceptions thrown, so I don't think that's impacting this issue.

Comment: You need to file a bug report, something very bad happened here.  You can limp along by comparing with Timeout.Infinity but you of course shouldn't have to.

Comment: Is there an equivalent to GetLastError() that I can call in my Xamarin Android/iOS application?  The documentation for WaitForMultipleObjects() says that's how you find out why you got WAIT_FAILED

Comment: File it as a bug report against Xamarin?  Against .NET itself?